# iterating and editing in pandas data frame (python)

Tags: pandas

I need to modify a column of my pandas dataframe, depending on the boolean value of another column. suppose I have one column of values, one column of true/false, and I want to sum 1 to those values with corresponding bool true. I tried with iterrows, but this make a copy of the dataframe and doesn't modify it.

Thank you!

input:

```
   val    bool
a   1.0   true
b   2.3   false
...
```

output:

```
   val    bool
a  2.0    true
b  2.3    false
```

Comment: `df['val'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['val'] + [0,1][row['bool']], axis=1)`

Comment: Don't use `bool` as a column name, plus your values, if they are supposed to be booleans, are invalid, they should be `True`, `False` not `true`, `false`

Answer (score 0):

Use `loc` to create a boolean mask and update the values using this mask, example:

```py
In [157]:

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.random.randn(5), 'b':[True,False,True,True,False]})
df

Out[157]:
          a      b
0 -1.666632   True
1  1.518392  False
2 -0.340623   True
3 -0.233279   True
4 -0.169503  False

[5 rows x 2 columns]
In [158]:
# determine the locations where we have a True value for the boolean mask
df.loc[df.b==True,'a']
Out[158]:
0   -1.666632
2   -0.340623
3   -0.233279
Name: a, dtype: float64
In [159]:
# now add one
df.loc[df.b==True,'a'] += 1
In [160]:

df
Out[160]:
          a      b
0 -0.666632   True
1  1.518392  False
2  0.659377   True
3  0.766721   True
4 -0.169503  False

[5 rows x 2 columns]
```